# Converting a template string as a type to a number

Tags: typescript, types

Is it possible to convert a type as a template string to a number?

E.g.:

```
type A = `${'1'}${'2'}` // should become 12, but becomes '12'
```

Comment: No it is not possible, see https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47141